# C# VLC playlist autoplay it working stop when next video

Tags: c#, vlc, playlist, autoplay

when first video ended switch to second video program stop working:

```
private void axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerEndReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < (listBox1.Items.Count - 1))
    {
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.next();
        listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
        listBox1.Update();
    }

    else
    {
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listBox1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I will make playlist autoplay from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJkie6OgwkE

Comment: You will have to explain what *"program stop working"* exactly means. Do you get any errors or exceptions? Did you try to debug?

Comment: Are there any errors occurring for your when your program stops working ?

Comment: No error but program stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerEndReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < (listBox1.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.next();
            listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
            listBox1.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            listBox1.Update();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just in put "axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();" stop everytime when change file