# Playing videos without lag or black screen in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I m working on this project, the client gave me the task to design the UI and embed videos. The backend code of that application is complete according to the client and the backend code is really poorly written with zero optimization.
The application is working perfectly, the application starts the main form loads **axWindowsMediaPlayer** form with it self and **axWindowsMediaPlayer** loads videos through resources. The issue is that in the beginning of each video the media player blinks, like if the playlist have 3 videos it'll blink 3 times and if I run the **axWindowsMediaPlayer** form separately it doesn't blink at all.
I've no idea what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Standart windows media player control is way too dated. It's basically good for nothing at this point. I'd just open nuget package list and look for any video player control. In case there is none, you can always just add a chromium-based webview element and play your video in there.

Comment: do you have recommendation about the media player? and how do i use chromium-based webview any leads? Note that its desktop app.

Comment: Yeah, LibVLCSharp should do it.

Comment: Theres a package called CefSharp, it adds chromium to your app.

Comment: yeah well I tried using LibVLC but apparently it doesn't support playlists meaning 1 control can only be used for one vides while I've to play 3 videos back to back, opening/showing different controls might slow the application

Comment: Libvlc does support playlists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124041/c-sharp-vlc-playlist-autoplay-it-working-stop-when-next-video

Comment: okay thanks, I was using vlccontrol for playing videos, I'll try using this